# Notation for a set $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$, $a_i \in \{0,1\}$ for $i = 1,2,3,4$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

What notation should I use for the set of the form

$$\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$$

where $a_i \in \{0,1\}$ for $i = 1,2,3,4$?

It's an output from an indicator function that is evaluated over some "domain" $\{b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4\}$. I.e. it produces 0 or 1 for each $b_i$. So the result (I think) should be a set $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$. Since the input is also a set of four elements. It makes no sense to consider the output as $\{0,1\}$ as then all "sequences" the indicator function produces could be the same.

Comment: There isn't any standard notation for this.

Comment: Thomas is right. There is no standard way of writing this

Comment: I was thinking there could be some "binary set" or some sort of.

Comment: If it is a set, it is either $\{0\}$, $\{1\}$ or $\{0,1\}$. I guess you would like a multiset or a sequence.

Comment: It's an output from an indicator function that is evaluated over some "domain" $\{b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4\}$. I.e. it produces 0 or 1 for each $b_i$. So the result (I think) should be a set $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$. Since the input is also a set of four elements. It makes no sense to consider the output as $\{0,1\}$ as then all "sequences" the indicator function produces could be the same.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function, I've probably understood this wrong. That is doesn't produce sequences such as $(1,0,1,0)$, even if set $X=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$ and $|A|=2$.

Answer (score 2):

A set is an unordered collection of elements.  $\{1,1,0,1\}$ is no different from $\{0,1\}$.

It appears that OP is looking for an ordered collection of four elements.  The natural notation for this is a *function*.  We define $$f:\{b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4\}\to \{0,1\}.$$

We can also use a shorthand to denote the function, via an ordered 4-tuple, e.g. $$f \text{ "is" } (a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4)$$where each $a_i\in\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

What you are speaking about are not sets. Sets are collections of elements without any order. There are only three sets composed by only zeros and ones: $\{\}, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{0,1\}$.

What you are speaking about are $n$-uples. Just use $()$ instead of $\{\}$ e.g.:
$$
(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) = (0,1,1,0).
$$

Comment: It's odd though since this is an output from a random variable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable), $X_i: \Omega \rightarrow E$, that is an indicator function. There it says that $E$ should be a set.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function, I've probably understood this wrong. That is doesn't produce sequences such as $(1,0,1,0)$, even if set $X=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$ and $|A|=2$.